# How can I call Kotlin methods with reified generics from Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, reification

I have the following method in Kotlin:

```
inline fun <reified T> foo() {

}
```

If I try to call this from Java like this:

```
myObject.foo();
```

OR like this:

```
myObject.<SomeClass>foo();
```

I get the following error:

> java: foo() has private access in MyClass

How can I call the `foo` method from Java?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's no way to call Kotlin `inline` functions with reified type parameters from Java because they must be transformed and inlined at the call sites (in your case, `T` should be substituted with the actual type at each call site, but there's much more compiler logic for `inline` functions than just this), and the Java compiler is, expectedly, completely unaware of that.

Comment: thanks a lot~ brb refactor java code bit by bit, to kotlin

Comment: To make the conversion easier you can define an overload which consumes a Class<T> instead of the reified type in the implementation as an overload. ```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> help() = help(T::class.java);
fun <T> help(cls: Class<T>) { ... }
``` 
This way you may call it via a reified generic in Kotlin and using class object in Java`

Answer (score 2):

The `inline` functions declared without `reified` type parameters can be called from Java as regular Java functions. But the ones declared with the `reified` type parameters are not callable from Java.

Even if you call it using the reflection like following:

```
Method method = MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("foo", Object.class);
method.invoke(new MyClass(), Object.class);
```

You get the `UnsupportedOperationException: This function has a reified type parameter and thus can only be inlined at compilation time, not called directly.`

If you have access to the code of the function, removing the `reified` modifier in some cases works. In other cases, you need to make adjustment to the code to overcome the type erasure.