# Why an inline function defined in a Kotlin file cannot be used in Java code?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to understand why I cannot use my inline function defined in a Kotlin file in my Java code?

**Project details**

Kotlin: 1.5.20 - Java: 15.0.1

Mixed code (Java + Kotlin). I have same package structure both in Java & Kotlin as below:

`com.app.company.util`.Util.java

`com.app.company.util`.Util.kt

In `Util.kt` I have an inline function as below:

```
val commonMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()

inline fun <reified T> parseJson(content: String): T {
   return commonMapper.readValue(content)
}
```

I noticed that since I have the same name `Util` for both Java class and Kotlin file, If I want to refer to the Kotlin file I have to use `UtilKt`. I found this by decompiling the Kotlin file.

Interestingly, only `commonMapper` is exposed by `getCommonMapper()` method not `parseJson`.

Could someone please help me understand why `parseJson` is not visible from Java?

Comment: This is really interesting. Just to narrow it down a bit, it's not an issue with inline functions specifically, but has to do with the reified parameter. As soon as that's removed everything works as expected.

Comment: If the issue is reified parameters, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741780/how-can-i-call-kotlin-methods-with-reified-generics-from-java) is probably a better dup.

Comment: That defintiely answers the question. The current duplicate doesn't seem to address the issue, as the inline function by itself works fine.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I added it, but the first question says that calling inline functions from Java is not possible at all.

Comment: It does seem to say that @MarkRotteveel, but using `UtilKt.parseJson(...)` (as in the OP's question) does indeed work.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel *Calling* inline functions is fine. They'll just behave like ordinary functions. The point that answer is making is that they won't magically inline in Java like they do in Kotlin. The issue is `reified`, not `inline`.